# C# Compare Column names and add values

Tags: c#, datatables

I am new to C# so i dont know if this is easy.
I have two Datatables
Table1

| abc.Field2 | abc.dfg.Field3 | abc.Field1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value2 | Value3 | Value1 |
| Value2 | Value3 | Value1 |
| Value2 | Value3 | Value1 |
| Value2 | Value3 | Value1 |

Table2

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |

I need to check by column name in two tables and add value in correct column in table2

like
Table2 after

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |

Take care i need a generic solution because there several tables to check and update i cant go with something like column.columnname["Field1"] etc...

Can anyone Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename the existing columns :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("abc.Field2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("abc.Field3", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("abc.Field1", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Value2", "Value3", "Value1"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Value2", "Value3", "Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Value2", "Value3", "Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Value2", "Value3", "Value1" });

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
            {
                int index = col.ColumnName.IndexOf(".");
                col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Substring(index + 1);
            }

 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much with your solution and ImportRow after that i solved my problem...Thank you again all for the help...